# Jmeter not working while starting in linux

Tags: jmeter, command-line-interface, redhat

i'm trying to use jmeter on redhat using command line
i used below command :

**./jmeter.sh -n -t absolute_path/test.jmx -l absolute_path/Results/results.jtl**

On firing i get below error :

**An error occurred: kg/apc/jmeter/vizualizers/CompositeResultCollector : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0**

Answer (score 1):

As per [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) project main page:

> The prerequisite is to run **JMeter 2.12** or above with a **Java 7**.

Upgrade your JRE or JDK to version 7 or above.

In general it's better to use the most recent version of Java as issues are being fixed in the latest version and then being backported into previous ones.

See [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) for more detailed explanation of above and few others JMeter performance tuning tips and tweaks.

Comment: is there any way i can force jmeter to use another version of java ?

Answer (score 0):

You're using **Third Party plugins**, hence you need to add the required jar in lib/ext so that it works.

If you are using old version of java upgrade to latest.

Comment: is there any way i can force jmeter to use another version of java ? Thanks.

Comment: Open jmeterw.cmd available in bin folder and set your own java path, then run jmeterw.cmd to open jmeter